# Retrieving image from postgresql database using Yii2 (php)

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2, bytea

We have a problem retrieving uploaded image from postgres database with yii2

we store image with that way to the db:

```
$data = pg_escape_bytea(file_get_contents($model->CheckIfAvatarExists(Yii::$app->user->identity->username)));

$profile->passphoto = new Expression("'{$data}'");
$profile->save();
```

stores image perfectly

but when we try to display image, it is not working:

```
header('Content-type: image/png');

echo pg_unescape_bytea(  $profile->passphoto);
```

I think the big problem is data after escaped it wont back to original be unescape

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this user-contributed comment in [pg_unescape_bytea](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-unescape-bytea.php) online doc:

> PostgreSQL 9.0 introduced "hex" as the new default format for encoding
>   binary data. Because "pg_unescape_bytea" only works with the old
>   "escape" format, you need to do pg_query('SET bytea_output =
>   "escape";'); before executing your select queries.

In fact, it's only true when the client library is **older than 9.0** (libq.so.5.2 I believe, now EOL'ed).

If that is your case, that explains the problem of wrong unescaping.

To force `bytea_output` to `escape` to decode properly, you may either :

- dynamically with `SET bytea_output=escape;` as a SQL command in the session
- or statically for the whole database: `ALTER DATABASE SET bytea_output=escape;`
- or in `postgresql.conf` for the whole instance.

The ideal solution would be to upgrade the `libpq` client library to a newer version, in which case none of this is necessary, it just works.